# Custom range bins in Pandas (interval starting always from zero)

Tags: pandas, data-binding

I use:

```
bins = pd.cut(data['R10rank'], list(np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1)))
sum=data.groupby(bins)['Ret20d'].agg(['count', 'mean'])
```

to create stats like:

```
    count   mean
R10rank     
(0.0, 0.1]  1044    4.782833
(0.1, 0.2]  809 5.527745
(0.2, 0.3]  746 5.181306
(0.3, 0.4]  706 4.034747
(0.4, 0.5]  627 3.119654
(0.5, 0.6]  585 1.977387
(0.6, 0.7]  609 -0.602742
(0.7, 0.8]  493 -2.745312
(0.8, 0.9]  412 -2.476791
(0.9, 1.0]  374 -6.364374
```

Next I would like to see bins that would aggregate stats over different intervals of value.

Like:

```
<0.1
<0.3
<0.5
>0.5
>0.7
etc
```

thus the second line would contain count and mean for all values in R10rank that have value 0-3. The fourth line would create count and mean for all values in R10rank that has value >0.5

Can I use pd.cut for that too? If not, what would be the easier way?

Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't use the bins for that. It becomes ambiguous if you have a cut-off value that doesn't align with a bin edge. Just loop through your cuts and use stuff like `df[df.R10rank < 0.1].Ret20d.agg(['count', 'mean'])`. Grouping is typically used for 1:1 mapping of rows to groups. In this case rows can belong to multiple groups

Comment: Also, is the aggregation over intervals weighted at the interval level, or by the counts within each bin? (That either makes my above comment moot or even more relevant, resepctively :P)

Comment: ALollz thank you for the tip. df[df.R10rank < 0.1].Ret20d.agg(['count', 'mean']) looks like a better way

Answer (score 0):

You can check with `expanding`

```
df['New']=df['count']*df['mean']
df.expanding(min_periods=1).sum().assign(mean=lambda x : x['New']/x['count'])
Out[105]: 
            count      mean           New
R10rank                                  
(0.0,0.1]  1044.0  4.782833   4993.277652
(0.1,0.2]  1853.0  5.108054   9465.223357
(0.2,0.3]  2599.0  5.129080  13330.477633
(0.3,0.4]  3305.0  4.895313  16179.009015
(0.4,0.5]  3932.0  4.612165  18135.032073
(0.5,0.6]  4517.0  4.270933  19291.803468
(0.6,0.7]  5126.0  3.691911  18924.733590
(0.7,0.8]  5619.0  3.127121  17571.294774
(0.8,0.9]  6031.0  2.744297  16550.856882
(0.9,1.0]  6405.0  2.212425  14170.581006
```